# Dynamic shaped (maybe fluid?) div with CSS or jQuery

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I have a big div which includes two divs. These smaller divs have to be in the same row, so I do it with "display:inline-block". But when the second div's text goes longer, that div goes to one row down. So, what I want to do is, making the second div some kind of fluid so it stays at the same row, and then rest of it goes down.

Here I have an example picture from Paint:

[image: Fluid div example]

I'm looking for a solution with CSS or jQuery which I can handle easily.
Hope I could explain, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `#text` div a style of `float: left;` and place it before the `#secondText` div in the source order. This will force your `#secondText` content to wrap around `#text`.

```
<div id="text">Text</div>
<div id="secondText">Another text continues here</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#text { float: left; }
```

Comment: Thank you, I also replaced "display:inline-block" with just "inline !important" and works perfect. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply `display:inline` for both the inner divs as in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/FJr5D/)